# Как извлечь содержимое внутри каждого тега <a href>?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, веб-скрейпинг

Я работаю над проектом, который предполагает извлечение некоторых данных с веб-сайта. В частности, меня интересует название каждой категории вместе с ее описанием.

Я рассматривал возможность использования библиотек веб-скрапинга, таких как BeautifulSoup, в Python, но не знаю, как перемещаться по каждой ссылке на категорию, чтобы получить необходимую информацию.

На веб-сайте указано несколько названий категорий, и каждая категория имеет собственную страницу с параметрами и описаниями. Я не уверен, как программно «нажимать» на каждую ссылку, чтобы получить данные.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://docs.derivative.ca/Category:CHOPs"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="mw-pages")
print(results.prettify())
chop_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="mw-content-ltr")
for chop_element in chop_elements:
    print(chop_element, end="\n"*2)

<li><a href="/Analyze_CHOP" title="Analyze CHOP">Analyze CHOP</a></li>
<li><a href="/Angle_CHOP" title="Angle CHOP">Angle CHOP</a></li>
<li><a href="/Attribute_CHOP" title="Attribute CHOP">Attribute CHOP</a></li>
<li><a href="/Audio_Band_EQ_CHOP" title="Audio Band EQ CHOP">Audio Band EQ CHOP</a></li>
Website is https://docs.derivative.ca/Category:CHOPs
```

Как лучше всего перемещаться по каждой ссылке на категорию и извлекать необходимые данные? Однако я не совсем уверен, что делаю, и не уверен, правильно ли я проверил структуру HTML. Я ищу рекомендации о том, как подойти к этой проблеме.

Comment: Программно нажимать на кнопки не получится. Нужно отправлять новый запрос `requests.get()`. Советую почитать документацию BS4 https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что уже не актуально для Вас, но оставлю свой ответ тут, возможно кому-то пригодится.

У Вас получилось собрать ссылки на категории, вам всего лишь необходимо добавить к этим ссылкам домен, и отправить **GET** запрос через **requests** на каждую категорию (перейти по ссылке), что бы потом собрать данные уже знакомым Вам способом, при помощи **BeautifulSoup**.

Вот пример кода, который возвращает ссылку на категорию, переходит по этой ссылке и получает название со страницы категории:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://docs.derivative.ca/Category:CHOPs"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="mw-pages")
chop_elements = results.find("div", class_="mw-content-ltr")
tag_a = chop_elements.find_all("a")
for a in tag_a:
    href = "https://docs.derivative.ca" + a.get("href")
    category = requests.get(href)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(category.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find("span", "mw-page-title-main").text
    print(f"Ссылка - {href}")
    print(f"Название категории - {title}")
```

Результат:

```
Ссылка - https://docs.derivative.ca/Ableton_Link_CHOP
Название категории - Ableton Link CHOP
Ссылка - https://docs.derivative.ca/Analyze_CHOP
Название категории - Analyze CHOP
Ссылка - https://docs.derivative.ca/Angle_CHOP
Название категории - Angle CHOP
...
```